# Mongodb aggregate pipeline. How to push to array?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I use `mongdb` aggregate pipeline for the format results.

My goal is to push `$value` object from the pipeline to `array`.

```
...
{ $addFields: {'array': push("$value") }}
...
```

Comment: Use `$concatArrays`.
Something like `{ $addFields: {"array": {"$concatArrays":["$array", "$value"]}}}`

Comment: yes it is what I am looked, just I guess you did a small mistake, because `"$value"` should be in array.  `{ $addFields: {"array": {"$concatArrays":["$array", ["$value"]]}}}`